# scrape text from a web form field that displays a current value and allows for input

Tags: python, web-scraping

**Goal:** use Python to scrape the value of 225 from the person score web form field; this field allows for user input and *I think is* dynamically populated by javascript?

**Picture of Form:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1011" name="Lead Score" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-form-num-field" title="" style="width: 189px;">
```

**Javascript that generates form values?**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


target_url = ['www.website_login.com','www.website_I_want_second_page.com']

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\chrome_driver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(target_url[0])
driver.find_element_by_id("loginUsername").send_keys("login")
driver.find_element_by_id("loginPassword").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
driver.get(target_url[1])
lead_detail_page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(lead_detail_page, 'html.parser')

form_item_ids = []

for tag in soup.findAll(class_ = "x-form-item"):
    form_item_ids.append(tag.get("id"))

for i in form_item_ids:
    test = soup.find(id=i).get_text()
    print(test)
```

**Result of Code:**

[image]

Comment: what's  the error you're getting?

Comment: there is no error, the .get_text() function returns no text for the id associated with person score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility, that person score value is added by javascript after retrieving page source using `lead_detail_page = driver.page_source`. It would make sense to try retrieve its value using selenium WebDriverWait, waiting for value of the input element being not empty:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# delay for waiting in seconds
DELAY = 30

# helper class which allows to wait for inputs value to be not empty
class wait_for_value_not_empty(object):
    
    def __init__(self, locator, attribute = 'value', value = ''):
        self.locator = locator
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.value = value

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_attribute = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).get_attribute(self.attribute)
            return element_attribute is not None and element_attribute != self.value
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

# wait for value to be filled
WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(wait_for_value_not_empty((By.ID, "ext-comp-1011")))

# retrieve value
person_score = driver.find_element_by_id("ext-comp-1011").get_attribute('value')

print(person_score)
```

Comment: this worked for me but only when I used EC.visibility_of_element_located(), thank you for the idea!